# Allow duplicate entry

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Most topics about avoid duplicate entry, but I want to allow. here is controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|string',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'phone' => 'required|numeric|digits:11',
    'type' => 'required'
]);
```

Using `passport`

**Model:**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'phone', 'type',
];
```

But it not let me to insert duplicate entry:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
>   entry '0955559777' for key
>             'users_phone_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>             values (mike, s22@s.com, 0955559777, 1, 2019-11-11 08:16:34, 2019-11-11 08:16:34))

It said `users_phone_unique` but I don't set phone be unique. any idea?

Comment: Check your migration you should have define it there

Comment: @SalmanZafar you right, because it made by `passport` I forgot to check that. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your users table migration file you set phone as **unique**
So you need to change it.cut down the unique key from migration. &

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

or write a new migration & make set it without unique

Answer (score 5):

Create new migration like this

```
php artisan make:migration remove_unique_key_from_user_table --table=users
```

Now Open this migration and drop unique key constraint method here like this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropUnique('users_phone_unique');
    });
}
```

after done run again migration

```
php artisan migrate
```